# When is work done NOT frame dependent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, work, friction

In general, we know work done by a force depends on frame of motion of observer, but this is not always the case,

for example, take the case of static friction and consider the NET work (sum of work on both bodies) done by it.
This is zero, no matter the frame.

Similarly the work done by Tension and Normal force is also zero no matter the frame.
All of there forces can be considered the so called "constraint forces".

I wonder if there exists a force, or at least a specific, non trivial, case of force, where the work it done is always constant (non necessarily zero) no matter the frame.

My textbook had a problem similar to this but instead of considering complete frame independence it just wanted to show that 2 specific frames had same net work and i wanted to know if this generalized to all frames

the problem from my txt book being-
A ball of mass m rolls of a hill of height H (frictionless) onto a plank of mass M (friction of coefficient u), find the net work done by friction till relative motion stops. a) in frame of ground and b) in frame of plank

and when you calculate these, surprise surprise, they are the same
now, does this generalize to all frames, and if it does, is there an intuitive way to see it?
i do have an intuition that kinetic friction behaves "nicely" ie, like a conservative force, as long as we never change our direction of motion, although i don't know if that helps anything

I originally thought to try to assume our frame has an acceleration a and solve for work to see its independent of a or not, but then realized that there are frames of non constant acceleration too, and even if i somehow solve for all frames, it doesn't give me any intuition as to why this is true (if it is)

Comment: > *"consider the NET work (sum of work on both bodies) done by it. "* That is sum of two works, by two forces.  If this sum is zero, then it is zero in all frames. Work of single force is frame-dependent.

Comment: Strange that you would cite examples where no work is done as examples of where work is frame independent(???)

Comment: those are the only ones i could think of

do you mean to say that if non-zero work is done, it must be frame dependent

Answer (score 1):

In this question it is easier to deal with power rather than work. The power of a force is $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$. If we transform to a frame moving at velocity $\vec u$ then the power in the new frame is $P’=\vec F \cdot (\vec v + \vec u)$.

To find when work is not frame dependent we can set $P=P’$ and simplify. $$\vec F \cdot \vec v= \vec F \cdot (\vec v + \vec u)$$$$0=\vec F \cdot \vec u$$ This quantity is $0$ if $\vec F=0$, $\vec u=0$, or if $\vec F$ is perpendicular to $\vec u$.

For the work to be frame invariant, the power must be independent of $\vec u$, including non-zero and non-perpendicular $\vec u$. So the last two options do not qualify and the only way for the work done by a force to be frame invariant is for $\vec F=0$

Similarly, for multiple forces the sum of the power is frame invariant if the sum of the forces is $0$. In other words, if the sum of the forces does not accelerate the system then the sum of the work is frame invariant.

Comment: But this doesnt work if the frame is non inertial, does it?

Comment: Yes, it is also non-relativistic. This is based on the Galilean transform between frames

Comment: what kind of forces (in action-reaction pair) would do constant net work, in all frames, inertial or not